# Как правильно написать слово "катастрофа"?

Tags: орфография, лексика

1. ***Катастрофа*** — известное слово.  Но в одном из печатных изданий увидела такую запись: котострофа!

Правильность написания можно проверить **по словарю**. Также есть другие слова  с приставкой  ката-:  ***каталог, катаклизм, катапульта.*** Можно же запомнить! Есть этимологический словарь:

**Катастро́фа.** Заимств. в первой половине XIX в. из франц. яз., где catastrophe < лат. catastropha «резкий поворот, неожиданное событие» — из греч. сложения kata «вниз» и strophē «поворот». (Греческая приставка  ***kata***  многозначная, обозначает движение вниз, усиление, переходность или завершение процесса».)

2. **Как можно писать с такими ошибками?** Может, что-то изменилось и теперь так правильно?

А вы как думаете?

Comment: Это  *котостроф**а́***. Кошачья строфа, строфа кота. :))

Comment: Сами догадались?)  Или видели где?

Comment: Нет, не видел. Леовопросы делают своё дело.

Comment: Записали бы ответ,  А я добавлю, где видела)

Comment: А что писать? Это, оказывается, сериал и игра.

Comment: Ну издание изданию рознь. Сэкономили  на редакторе и все.

Comment: Серж, это кот/о/строфА. Календарь на 2024 год.

Answer (score 0):

В книжном магазине я увидела тематический календарь — ***Котострофа***.

Там были котоафоризмы на каждый месяц. Вот самый первый:

*"В 2024-м году у вас все будет хорошо. **Но это не точно"**.*

Так что **с котами** нам будет не скучно. И это уж точно.